# Передвижение старых статей вниз

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Я столкнулся с небольшой трудностью.

У меня информационный портал, на главной странице выкладываются ссылки на статьи ***(картинки с href)***. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при добавлении новой картинки, она вставала сверху, а остальные перемещались вниз. В интернете читал, что это можно сделать с помощью `position: relative`, но у меня никак не получается.

```css
div.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 220px;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -125px 0 0 -125px;
}

.two {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">
    <p>
      <a href="notes/10-maloizvestnykh-faktov-o-lune.php"><img id "icon" src="http://localhost/images/notes/10-maloizvestnykh-faktov-o-lune.jpg" width="310" height="185"></a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <p>
      <a href="notes/2.php"><img id "icon" src="http://localhost/images/notes/two.jpg" width="310" height="185"></a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <p>
      <a href="notes/3.php"><img id "icon" src="http://localhost/images/notes/three.jpg" width="310" height="185"></a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="four">
    <p>
      <a href="notes/4.php"><img id "icon" src="http://localhost/images/notes/four.jpg" width="310" height="185"></a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="five">
    <p>
      <a href="notes/5.php"><img id "icon" src="http://localhost/images/notes/five.jpg" width="310" height="185"></a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="six">
    <p>
      <a href="notes/6.php"><img id "icon" src="http://localhost/images/notes/six.jpg" width="310" height="185"></a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="seven">
    <p>
      <a href="notes/7.php"><img id "icon" src="http://localhost/images/notes/seven.jpg" width="310" height="185"></a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="eight">
    <p>
      <a href="notes/8.php"><img id "icon" src="http://localhost/images/notes/eight.jpg" width="310" height="185"></a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="nine">
    <p>
      <a href="notes/9.php"><img id "icon" src="http://localhost/images/notes/nine.jpg" width="310" height="185"></a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="ten">
    <p>
      <a href="notes/10.php"><img id "icon" src="http://localhost/images/notes/ten.jpg" width="310" height="185"></a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="eleven">
    <p>
      <a href="notes/11.php"><img id "icon" src="http://localhost/images/notes/eleven.jpg" width="310" height="185"></a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="twelve">
    <p>
      <a href="notes/12.php"><img id "icon" src="http://localhost/images/notes/twelve.jpg" width="310" height="185"></a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это клон вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927108/Передвижение-старых-div-вниз